# iOS Swift3 ViewController never calls deinit

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, deinit

I have 4 UIViewControllers, all Modally Segued to using Storyboards, all unwind to same root view controller, BUT 1 view controller never calls deinit. I know deinit is not called for this specific VC because I have print statements inside the deinit.

I'm not retaining any reference cycles on the problem VC, nor do I have any references to any of these views. The segue is defined in the storyboard with appropriate identifier and performSegue is called inside the rootVC to each of these 4 VCs.

The only difference between the 4 VCs is one with a problem uses a UITableView and no the VC is not a UITableViewController, the tableView is embedded using extensions and works just fine.

The very nature of this app is to cycle through 4 screens sequentially, then pop back to the first VC. So I'm worried this VC that never deinits is just leaking outright, for no clear reason.

Please help and thank you.

Comment: How do you know you don't have any reference cycles? Have you verified this through Instruments?

Comment: I ran Instruments, honestly don't know how to use it that well. But what I do know, like I said above, I'm not creating or holding onto any references to the problem view controller. How can it retain cycles on itself if there's no code to do it?